# Set a variable value depending on value in a conditional variable

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, var

I need something like this

```
var String = "";
if (i == "Inbox") {var String = "Inbox"}
if (i == "Sent") {var String = "String"}

var showMailList = this.props.Data.String.map
```

I know it's simple question, but I can't find it in google. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can access an objects properties through a string with `this.props.Data['somestringValue'].map`. However accessing global variables this way you would need to use the window object.

Comment: do you need the content of `'String'` or `'Sent'` in the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the property with bracket notation

```
var showMailList = this.props.Data[ i ].map
```

`i` will your property `Inbox` or `Sent`